# Display query alphabetically

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a browse page that pulls info from 2 tables in a database then displays it. It works properly but I would like it to display alphabetically.  Any suggestions?

```
<?php

$serch="SELECT mint.*, COUNT(items.item_id) as total FROM mint LEFT JOIN items ON mint.mint_id=items.item_mint group by mint_id;";

$items=mysql_query($serch); 
while($it=mysql_fetch_array($items)) {
?>          
<div class="product_box">

<h3 style="font-size:15px;"><a href="mintitem.php?id=<?php echo $it['mint_id']; ?>"><?php echo $it['mint_name']; ?></a> (<?php echo $it['total']; ?>)</h3>
</div>          
<?php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add order by in your query

```
$serch="SELECT mint.*, COUNT(items.item_id) as total FROM mint LEFT JOIN items ON mint.mint_id=items.item_mint group by mint_id ORDER BY mint_id ASC;";
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to add `ORDER BY` clause in your query, EG

```
SELECT ...
FROM...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY...
ORDER BY columnName ASC
```

WHERE `columnName` is the name of the column you want the records to be sorted. Additionally, you can define multiple columns in the order by clause, eg `ORDER BY col1 ASC, col2 DESC,...`